# Java Web Start - adding the CA cert does not get rid of warning

Tags: java, security, ssl, jnlp

I have a Java Web Start application launched via a JNLP file (hosted on a web server) . The server certificate is signed using an internal CA. This internal CA is added to my browsers, so my browser does not show an https warning.

However, with JNLP, when I import the certificate of the internal CA into JavaControlPanel->Security->Manage Certificates->Signer CA/Secure Site CA, I still get the warnings. 
The only way I can get rid of the warnings is by importing the server (which host the JNLP) certificate into the "Secure Site" tab. This does not seem right since I will have to repeat it for all the servers which use a cert signed by our internal CA. Ideally, if I import the CA, certs issued by the CA should also be trusted. 
Running Java 8u101.

Comment: Looks like issue, Did you see this problem only in 8u101. Earlier versions of java where working fine? I mean is it a regression?

Comment: Seen it in earlier Java8 versions as well. Will test out on Java 7 and update.

Comment: Probably you should raise issue against java.